# how to log time against a task in AtTask/workfront REST api

Tags: attask, workfront-api

ive figured out the basics of AtTask api's, login, grabbing session id, etc, but haven't figured out how to log time against a task or project yet.

sniffing the actual website i see we hit `https://my_site.attask-ondemand.com/update/logTime` with an `ID` of my task and `objCode=TASK` which makes sense.

but then there is `dataList` with some kind of hashed object and the date and hours ive entered.

I can't find anything about these methods/how to do it from REST api on the developer site, so was hoping someone somewhere could help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is Hour.

Check out the document for hour at https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/220633507-API-Explorer

and to specify what you want to log time to you specify the Issue ID (opTaskID), Project ID (projectID) or Task ID (taskID) from there you have the option o update time against the project, task or even the Issue. You will need to specify where you want the time to be associated with, use field `"noteObjCode" = "OPTASK"` or `TASK` or `PROJ`.

An example url would look like this

```
https://yourdomain.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/hour/?updates={"opTaskID":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","noteObjCode":"OPTASK","hours":"0.25","description":"update%20time","status":"SUB"}&sessionID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&method=post.
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but would this not associate with a date? in the `dataList` object above, the post was of 'mm-dd-yyyy:hours' so that the site could update the specific day you were entering hours for. not just a total amount to increment by?

Comment: To associate this entry with a date you need to specify "entryDate":"2014-01-01" in the updates array. If not specified it will default to today. An entry to hours creates an actual entry in the hours section. Posts that are on the same day will be grouped together. You are able to specify the description and then the description will appends to that date, it does not override it.

Comment: Just a note that the workfront (previously atTask) api is not on version 7. So the url in this answer isn't 100% valid anymore. Check the [up to date docs](https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003574147-API-Basics) to modify this to work with newer version